# play/pause webview iframe video

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-jetpack-compose

Need help, I want to create one icon button that will play/pause for iframe video on webview. How to I implement onPause in my coding below?

```
@Composable
fun Stream(activity: ComponentActivity) {
    val frameVideo = "<html><iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"src=\"https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/168/original/Record.mp4\" frameborder= \"0\" allow= \"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe></html></html>"
    val state = rememberWebViewState(url = frameVideo)
    val navigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
    val chromeClient = remember { CustomChromeClient(activity) }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = {  }) {
            Text("Play/Pause")
        }

        WebView(
            state = rememberWebViewStateWithHTMLData(data = frameVideo),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            navigator = navigator,
            chromeClient = chromeClient, //This is what concerns us for fullscreen mode
            onCreated = { webView ->
                webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
                webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8")
                //configuring the webview settings here such as enabling javascript
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Expecting button that will play/pause for iframe video

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun Stream(activity: ComponentActivity) {
    val frameVideo = "<html><iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/168/original/Record.mp4\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe></html></html>"
    val state = rememberWebViewState(url = frameVideo)
    val navigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
    val chromeClient = remember { CustomChromeClient(activity) }

    // Flag to track the video state (playing or paused)
    var isVideoPlaying by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            // Toggle the video state when the button is clicked
            isVideoPlaying = !isVideoPlaying
            // Execute JavaScript to play or pause the video
            state.webView?.evaluateJavascript(
                "var video = document.querySelector('iframe'); " +
                "if (video && video.contentWindow) { " +
                "   if (${'$'}{isVideoPlaying}) video.contentWindow.postMessage('play', '*'); " +
                "   else video.contentWindow.postMessage('pause', '*'); " +
                "}",
                null
            )
        }) {
            Text(if (isVideoPlaying) "Pause" else "Play")
        }

        WebView(
            state = state,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            navigator = navigator,
            chromeClient = chromeClient,
            onCreated = { webView ->
                webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**1. When the "Play/Pause" button is clicked, we toggle the isVideoPlaying state and then execute JavaScript code using evaluateJavascript on the WebView to either play or pause the embedded video based on the isVideoPlaying state.**

**2. The JavaScript code inside evaluateJavascript checks for the embedded video in the iframe and sends a "play" or "pause" message to control the video.**